# Application of Hahn-Banach Theorem in $\Bbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I'm trying to solve

> Let consider the space $\Bbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\|(x,y)\|_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}$ and let $Z$ be the subspace $$Z=\{(t,mt);t\in\Bbb{R}\},$$ for some $m\in\Bbb{R}$. Let $f\colon Z\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined by $f(t,mt)=t$.
>
> (a) For $1<p<\infty$ find the unique linear extension $\tilde{f}$ of $f$ defined over $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $\|\tilde{f}\|=\|f\|$.
>
> (b) For $p=1$, find two distincts extensions of $f$. Do the same for $p=\infty$.

I'm stucked in (a), and neither try (b) yet. I was thinking that the extension which works in (a) is $\tilde{f}(x,y)=y/m$. But I'm with big difficult to see what to do with the norms.

For any $(t,mt)\in Z$, we have that $$\|(t,mt)\|_p=|t|(1+|m|^p)^{1/p},$$ and $$|f(t,mt)|=|t|\leqslant|t|(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}=\|(t,mt)\|_p,$$ hence $\|f\|\leqslant1$. So the candidate to be the norm of $f$ is $1$. But I can't find the vector in $Z$ that does the work, neither usying some sequence in $Z$ that makes the norm be $1$.

So, I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: The norm of $f$ will be $\frac1{(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}}$.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that I understand your point. Instead the inequality $|t|\leqslant|t|(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}$ we make $|t|=\frac{|t|(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}}{(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}}$?

Comment: As an aside, that's a really nice exercise. Where is it from?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC, I guess that is an adaptation from an exercise of Kreyszig's book. In the book, he asks to give some example of extension in finite dimension. But about the exercise of post, my teacher put on our exercises list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, as it has correctly been observed, $\|f\|_{Z^*}=\frac{1}{(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}}$.

Note that $Z$ is a line that passes through the origin. Take the vertical line to $Z$ which is the subspace $W=\{(-mt,t):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. In order to define an extension of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ it suffices to define a value for the extension at the point $(-m,1)$, because $(-m,1)$ and $(1,m)$ are linearly idependent and span $\mathbb{R}^2$. The extensions are in one to one correspondence with the possible values of $(-m,1)$, so let's take an extension that assigns the value $c\in\mathbb{R}$ to the point $(-m,1)$. Let's denote this (unique) extension by $F_c$, so $F_c(-m,1)=c$ and $F_c(1,m)=f(1,m)=1$.

Write a point $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a linear combination of $(1,m)$ and $(-m,1)$, say $(x,y)=a\cdot(1,m)+b\cdot(-m,1)$. We have to solve the system (solve for $a,b$)
$$a-mb=x$$
$$ma+b=y$$
and by Cramer's rule we get that $a=\frac{x+my}{1+m^2}$ and $b=\frac{y-mx}{1+m^2}$. Therefore we have that
$$F_c(x,y)=\frac{x+my}{1+m^2}F_c(1,m)+\frac{y-mx}{1+m^2}F_c(-m,1)=\frac{x+my+c(y-mx)}{1+m^2}$$
Now $$\|F_c\|=\sup_{(x,y)\neq0}\frac{|F(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\cdot\sup_{x,y\neq0}\frac{|(1-mc)x+(c+m)y|}{(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}}\;\;\;\;(\star).$$

### Question 1

Let $q$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$, i.e. $1/p+1/q=1$. Then Using the [H"older inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) we have that $|(1-mc)x+(c+m)y|\leq\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q\cdot\|(x,y)\|_p$, so $$\|F_c\|\leq\frac{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q}{1+m^2}$$. On the other hand, take the vector $(x,y)=((1-mc)\cdot|1-mc|^{q-2},(c+m)\cdot|c+m|^{q-2})$. Note that $\|(x,y)\|_p=\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q^{q/p}$ so
$$\|F_c\|\geq\frac{|F_c(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|_p}=\frac{1}{1+m^2}\cdot\frac{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q^q}{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q^{q/p}}=\frac{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q}{1+m^2} $$
So we conclude that $$\|F_c\|=\frac{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q}{1+m^2}$$
Now in order to have an isometric extension we must choose $c$ so that $\|F_c\|=\|f\|_{Z^*}$, i.e.
$$\frac{\|(1-mc,c+m)\|_q}{1+m^2}=\frac{1}{(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}},$$
or equivalently
$$|1-mc|^q+|c+m|^q=\bigg(\frac{1+m^2}{(1+|m|^p)^{1/p}}\bigg)^{q}  $$
So one has to verify that this equation has a unique solution for $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

### Question 2

Suppose that $p=1$. Then the obvious inequality $|(1-mc)x+(c+m)y|\leq\max\{|1-mc|,|c+m|\}\cdot(|x|+|y|)$ together with $(\star)$ for $p=1$ yield
$$\|F_c\|\leq\frac{\max\{|1-mc|,|c+m|\}}{1+m^2}.$$
On the other hand, applying $F_c$ at $(1,0)$ and at $(0,1)$ yield $\|F_c\|\geq\frac{|1-mc|}{1+m^2}$ and $\|F_c\|\geq\frac{|c+m|}{1+m^2}$, so we have that $$\|F_c\|=\frac{\max\{|1-mc|,|c+m|\}}{1+m^2}.$$

we want the extension to be isometric, so we want $\|F_c\|=\|f\|_{Z^*}=\frac{1}{1+|m|}$, so we want
$$\frac{\max\{|1-mc|,|c+m|\}}{1+m^2}=\frac{1}{1+|m|}$$

so one has to verify that this equation has at least two solutions for $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $p=\infty$. In that case $\|f\|_{Z^*}=\frac{1}{\max\{1,|m|\}}$. Also, $$|F_c(x,y)|=\frac{|(1-mc)x+(c+m)y|}{1+m^2}\leq\frac{(|1-mc|+|c+m|)\max\{|x|,|y|\}}{1+m^2}$$
so $\|F_c\|\leq\frac{|1-mc|+|c+m|}{1+m^2}$. On the other hand, $$\|F_c\|\geq\frac{|x(1-mc)+y(c+m)|}{1+m^2}$$
for all $x,y\in\{-1,1\}$. Depending on the order of $1,m,c$ we can choose proper values of $x,y\in\{-1,1\}$ to establish the inequality
$$\|F_c\|\geq\frac{|1-mc|+|c+m|}{1+m^2}$$
so we conclude that $$\|F_c\|=\frac{|1-mc|+|c+m|}{1+m^2}.$$
We want an isometric extension, so we are looking for the values of $c$ so that
$$\frac{|1-mc|+|c+m|}{1+m^2}\equiv\|F_c\|=\|f\|_{Z^*}\equiv\frac{1}{\max\{1,|m|\}}$$

and one has to verify that this equation has at least two solutions for $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

A final comment: This seems too complicated to me. If I were you I would only care for $m=0$, since any other line can be obtained from the canonical axis system with a mere rotation. Anyway, I am unsure how one would solve the equations that arise in each case, all those absolute values make things somehow complicated. I believe the idea and the norm computations are correct though. If I have any mistakes, please point them out.

Comment: Your computations seems fine to me. But this really became complicated... I gonna think about the case $m=0$ and try to follow your steps to see what happen. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mathecm glad i could help!